# Files under the build folder are generated and shouldn't be edited

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know if there is any way to edit the `BuildConfig.java` file in Android Studio, as there is an error when I try to change a variable in that file. It says:

> Files under the build folder are generated and shouldn't be edited.

Every time I change the variable and build the project, it returns to the old one.

Comment: Rather than edit the BuildConfig file, you should be editing the buildscript, which creates the BuildConfig file. I'm wondering what you're trying to accomplish here, and there might be a better way of doing it, or an example we could provide of how to make that change to the BuildConfig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is any way to edit "BuildConfig.java" file in Android Studio

No. That is generated for you on each build.

However, depending on what it is that you are really trying to solve, you may be able to make changes in your module's `build.gradle` file that affect what goes into `BuildConfig`.

Comment: thank you , i found the variable in the module build.gradle and changed it